# Отправить форму с пустым file с помощью CURL

Tags: php, curl

Использую обертку для CURL https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class , не могу отправить пустую форму, но через браузер отправляется без проблем:

> ------WebKitFormBoundaryBxiCiV4ihQEhlxAg Content-Disposition: form-data; name="FileInput"; filename="" Content-Type:
>   application/octet-stream

Мое временное решение (запрос принимается сервером, но генерирует на нем постоянно файлы):

```
$FileInput = tempnam('', mt_rand());
rename($FileInput, $FileInput = substr($FileInput, 0, (strrpos($FileInput, "."))) . '.txt');
 $this->curl->post('http://site.com/' . $offer_id, array(
                'FileInput' => '@' . $FileInput,
                'txtPercent' => $percent
            ));
```

Сервер в ответ ругается, если сделать пустым                'FileInput' => ‘’ на то, что нет filename

Comment: Если я правильно понял вопрос, то вам нужно что-то типа такого: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32511502/how-can-i-force-a-empty-file-element-with-curl-and-php

Comment: @AK , да, погуглив тоже видел этот пост, вот только, как сделать это с используемым php-curl-class, а не на чистом CURL?

Comment: Такой библиотекой не пользовался раньше, но. Вы посмотрите [код библиотеки](https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class/blob/master/src/Curl/Curl.php#L559) и в post  передавайте $data не [массивом](https://github.com/php-curl-class/php-curl-class/blob/master/src/Curl/Curl.php#L172), а сформированным так, как выше указан body. Можно попробовать ещё такой упрощённый вариант:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071747/php-curl-multipart-form-data-with-application-octet-stream-for-a-blank-file

Comment: Хм. Ну смотрите: всё равно эта библиотека считает, что файл обязательно должен быть - в buildPostData строчки с CURLFile и тогда вам создавать временный файл, делать запрос, потом удалять (альтернативно: создать один раз и оставить как часть проекта). Либо формировать фейковые данные из несуществующего файла, тогда вручную собираете код из тех двух ссылок, что я приводил. Либо форкнуться, написать свою модификацию и предложить автору пулл-риквест ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не уверен, но судя по [этому вопросу](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13071747/php-curl-multipart-form-data-with-application-octet-stream-for-a-blank-file) должен помочь такой грязноватый хак:

```
 $this->curl->post('http://site.com/' . $offer_id, array(
                //'FileInput' => '@' . $FileInput,
                'attchmnt[0]"; FileInput=""'."\r\n".'Content-Type: octet-stream' => '',
                'txtPercent' => $percent
            ));
```

Comment: Спасибо, хак действительно работает, только вот так $data[$key . '"; filename=""'."\r\n".'Content-Type: octet-stream'] = '';